# Cabal: installing a Bash script alongside a library

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a non-Haskell executable (bash script) that I would like cabal to install in `~/.cabal/bin` along with my Haskell library. How can I achieve this simply with cabal?

Edit: as I mentioned in a comment below: installing specifically to `~/.cabal/bin` isn't crucial, I just need the script to be available in my library.

Comment: Does it have to end in `~/.cabal/bin`, or is being able to call it from your library enough?

Comment: I don't get the problem, can't you just do `cp path/to/bin-file ~.cabal/bin`?

Comment: @Tarrasch "...that I would like _cabal_ to install..." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @DanielWagner No, ultimately I just need to be able to call it from my library. I figured getting Cabal to place it in `~/.cabal/bin` would be the simplest way to do that. I'd be interested in a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cabal's `data-files` field to have some extra files installed, and then use the `getDataFileName` function created by cabal to retrieve the file. Details are available in [the documentation](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code) and [this blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html).

Comment: Binary executables should normally never be stored as data files, though.

Comment: @dflemstr Indeed, it seems that `data-files` is meant to be used for static content (images, for example). But if that's the case, how should executables be installed? In my case, I'm trying to install a bash script.

Comment: Cabal normally only builds Haskell executables. You could edit Setup.hs to add other build steps outside of Cabal.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since it appears to be the easiest way to achieve what I want.